# Passing a parameter into sql script

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

Right now I am able to execute a script from my website in an HTTPpost method.

```
string scriptDirectory = "c:\\Users\\user\\Documents";
                string sqlConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
                    "Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=ARES";
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(scriptDirectory);
                FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.sql");
                foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
                {
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fi.FullName);
                    string script = fileInfo.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
                    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
                    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
                    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

Atm the script is creating a new database (database is not dynamic yet). I want to pass in parameters that a user of the website enters and then pass that into the sql script. Basically I want them to choose the name of the database that is to be created.

The SQL command's are right at the beginning of the script.

```
CREATE DATABASE [This is where the name will be passed to]
GO
USE[This is where the name will be passed to]
```

Edit:

I have this code

```
SqlCommand createDbCommand = new SqlCommand();
        createDbCommand.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE [@DataBase]";
        createDbCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataBase", SqlDbType.Text);
        createDbCommand.Parameters["@DataBase"].Value = client.HostName;
```

Must I manually enter this into the top of my script now?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new SqlCommand and set the script `CommandText` to your script's text and then set parameters using `cmd.Parameters.Add`.

Using parameters with CRUD operations is simple enough (google for "t-sql parameters" for thousands of resources), however parameterising type names is more involved, for that there's a lengthy MSDN article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

If you're looking for something quick 'n' dirty, you could roll your own parameterisation system by putting replacement sequences in your sql files and using a regular expression to make each replacement, such as using the syntax "`{{fieldName}}`".

Comment: Could you give an example on how to use Parameters.Add, specifically on what you would enter into the script as a placement holder.

Comment: I've added some code. I just need to know if there is another way other than opening the file and modifiying it manually to enter that command.